# PHP Function from Inherited Class Requires Function from Another Class

Tags: php

I have this situation :

```
class User extends Database {

    public function validateLogin ($email, $password) {
       // some code here
    }

}

class General {
    public function encryptData ($data) {
       // some code here
    }
}
```

`$password` from `validateLogin` needs to be encrypted using `encryptData` function from `class General`, the problem is `class User` already extends / inherit `class Database` and PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance, right? how to solve this situation?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) if you are using PHP 5.4+.

Example:

```
trait encryptDataFunctions {
  public function encryptData($data) {
    // some code here
  }
}
```

Then use it in your classes:

```
class General {
  use encryptDataFunctions;
}

class User extends Database {
  use encryptDataFunctions;

  public function validateLogin ($email, $password) {
    $encrypted = $this->encryptData($password);
    //more code here
  }
}
```

Comment: br3nt : your solution is easy to read and understand. it's also clean. I like it.

Comment: Sometimes PHP can be elegant 

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `class General` to `validateLogin` method

```
public function validateLogin ($email, $password, General $General) {
   $encPassword = $General->encryptData($password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some sort of base method on the base class like so:

```
class Database {
  protected function encryptData($data) {
    // this is just to give an idea... you could cache the
    // General class, rather than create it on each method call
    // sky's the limit
    $x = new General();
    return $x->encryptData($data);
  }
}
```

Then you can use that factory method in the subclasses:

```
class User extends Database {
  public function validateLogin ($email, $password) {
    $encrypted = $this->encryptData($password);
  }
}
```

You can even override it if need be:

```
class UnsecuredUser extends Database {

  protected function encryptData($data) {
    return $data;
  }

  public function validateLogin ($email, $password) {
    $encrypted = $this->encryptData($password);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try making it a static method, and calling it directly without instantiating the General object:

```
class General {
    public static function encryptData ($data) {
       // some code here
    }
}

class User extends Database {
    public function validateLogin ($email, $password) {
       $encrypted = \General::encryptData($password);
       //more code here
    }    

}
```